# wordpress pagination ads extra slashes to url

Tags: wordpress

Working with custom post types I cant seem to get the pagination to work correct. All is working but when I click to the next page the url will get a extra slash in the url, not sure why this is happening but when using the pagination a lot will add every time a new slash to the url.

// out

```
site.com/projects/ ,  
site.com/projects//page/2,  
site.com/projects///page/3,  
site.com/projects////page/4 

...and so on.
```

// the code used

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type'      => 'projects', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged'          => $paged

    ) );


    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

       the_title();

    endwhile; 

        $total_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){

            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base'      => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format'    => '/page/%#%',
                'current'   => $current_page,
                'total'     => $total_pages,
                'prev_text' =>  esc_html__('volgende »', 'infrafocus'),
                'next_text' =>  esc_html__('« vorige' , 'infrafocus'),
            ));
        }

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes in the case of Custom post type pagination, you have to add the rewrite rule in your function.php 
Add Function like:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php/projects?page=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Please Refer this link for more information : https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: add_rewrite_rule('^projects/page/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=projectpage_id&paged=$matches[1]','top'); try this

Comment: or Try to 1) change  'base'      => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%', argument as per the wordpress document.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `'format'    => '/page/%#%',`  to `'format'    => 'page/%#%',`

Answer (score 1):

User format as below

```
'format'             => '?paged=%#%'
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: As mentioned i'm using nice urls so this is no option